# Removing first string character with substr in WordPress

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, substring, substr, bem

I am trying to remove the "|" from the file size span tag. The syntax of my javascript code so far does look fine, but it's not working quite yet.

From my understanding I am using the proper syntax for substr: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

In Chrome, I am getting this console error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined

In Firefox, I am getting this console error:

> Uncaught TypeError: innerTextString is undefined.

Also the "|" isn't being removed as intended. Any ideas where I am going wrong here?

Thank you in advance.

```js
<script>
    const prettyLinkRightFileSize = document.querySelectorAll('.prettyFileList .float_right:nth-child(1)');
    const innerTextString = prettyLinkRightFileSize.innerText;
    innerTextString.substr(0);
</script>
```

```css
.prettyFileList .float_right {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="prettyFileList">
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="prettylink">
            <span class="float_right">| Size 150 KB</span>
            <span class="float_right">28th Jan 2021</span> 
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: querySelector not querySelectorAll

Comment: @danronmoon I am referencing it from the api - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

You do not crop anything, when you use `innerTextString.substr(0)`, as it has the same amount of characters like the original String.

```
var e = "ThisisaText";
var t = e.substring(0);

Log.v("e", e);
Log.v("t", t);
```

Output:

```
"ThisisaText"
"ThisisaText"
```

additionally you select the Items via classname. So I recommend, you crop all Items with the same class to provide consistency.

Try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="prettyFileList">| Testsize</div>
</body>
<script>
    var c = document.getElementsByClassName('prettyFileList');
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; ++i) {
      var item = c[i];  
      item.innerHTML = item.innerHTML.substr(1);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> const prettyLinkRightFileSize = document.querySelector**All**('.prettyFileList .float_right:nth-child(1)');

> **const** innerTextString = prettyLinkRightFileSize.innerText;

**To**

```
   const prettyLinkRightFileSize = document.querySelector('.prettyFileList .float_right:nth-child(1)');`

   let innerTextString = prettyLinkRightFileSize.innerText;

   innerTextString = innerTextString.slice(1);

   console.log(innerTextString)
```

Answer (score 0):

querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live) NodeList. You need to use `prettyLinkRightFileSize[0].innerText`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```html
<script>
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.prettyFileList .float_right:first-child'))
    .map(element => element.innerText = element.innerText.substring(1));
</script>
```

It also **works with multiple elements** on your page!

If you do querySelectorAll you will get a nodeList with all elements matching the select statement. You have to iterate over these results to manipulate each of them (also if you only match one element: An array with one element still requires other treatment than the element it self).